# How to run pymongo aggregation query for large(200,000+ records) collection?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, data-analysis

I need to run an aggregation query for a large collection which has 200,000+ data records. And I want to run it with `pymongo`. I tried out the preferred method in the docs.

> pipeline = [...]
>
> db.command('aggregate', 'statCollection', pipeline=pipeline_aggregate)

But this returned an error saying `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument`.

Answer (score 0):

From the mongo documentation for [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#example)

> Changed in version 3.4: MongoDB 3.6 removes the use of aggregate
>   command without the cursor option unless the command includes the
>   explain option. Unless you include the explain option, you must
>   specify the cursor option.

either you can change `runCommand` to `aggregate pipeline` or provide an `cursor` in the command

**runCommand without `cursor`** -- error

```
> db.runCommand({aggregate : "coin_infos", pipeline : [ {$match : {"coin_code" : "BTC"}}]})
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument",
    "code" : 9,
    "codeName" : "FailedToParse"
}
```

**with `cursor`** --returns cursor

```
> db.runCommand({aggregate : "coin_infos", pipeline : [ {$match : {"coin_code" : "BTC"}}], cursor : {}})
{
    "cursor" : {
        "firstBatch" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5a4b07b2a0050c20a6be44b3"),
                "coin_code" : "BTC",
                "wallet_name" : "bitcoin",
                "deposite_txn_fee" : 3,
                "min_withdrawn" : 5,
                "withdrawn_txn_fee" : 0.001
            }
        ],
        "id" : NumberLong(0),
        "ns" : "bitcoin.coin_infos"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

**with `explain:true` and `no cursor`** --returns execution plan

```
> db.runCommand({aggregate : "coin_infos", pipeline : [ {$match : {"coin_code" : "BTC"}}], explain : true})
{
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {
                    "coin_code" : "BTC"
                },
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "bitcoin.coin_infos",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {
                        "coin_code" : {
                            "$eq" : "BTC"
                        }
                    },
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "filter" : {
                            "coin_code" : {
                                "$eq" : "BTC"
                            }
                        },
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used 
```> db.command('aggregate', 'statCollection', pipeline=pipeline_aggregate, cursor={})
```
But it also returned an error.
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.

Comment: @LasithNiroshan you need to use `allowDiskUse` to use temporary files, since dataset is huge

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using `allowDiskUse` option. So this is my answer.

> pipeline_2 = [...]
>
> db.command('aggregate', 'statCollection', pipeline=pipeline_2, allowDiskUse=True, cursor={})

Comment: `cursor` was missing in your query, that is the issue. Since the dataset is large `allowDiskUse` true to use temp files